# no puedo acceder a los puertos com alguien tiene idea?

Tags: puertos

Conecto el móvil la computadora  y no me aparecen los puertos com alguien tiene idea de que puede ser?
supongo que sera problema del móvil porque eh probado con otros y aparecen. pero necesito saber porque con un móvil no andan

Comment: Te refieres a que no aparecen los puertos bluetooth de tu dispositivo? En donde es que no aparecen? Al intentar hacer qué operación es que no los ves? Acaso puede que te estés refiriendo a que tu móvil no aparece en la lista de 'Connected Devices' de la pantalla 'Select Deployment Target' al intentar debuggear? Lo estas intentando hacer por cable o bluetooth? Son muchas preguntas. Coméntanos por favor un poco de contexto, acerca de que estas intentando hacer y cuando es que no ves el puerto.

Comment: Estoy intentando enviar mensajes a traves del movil conectado a la pc, esto lo intento hacer con comandos at (solo porque no eh encontrado otra solucion), bueno para esto conecto el movil en modo de modem, y para relizar la coneccion con el mismo deberia aparecer el puerto com en el administrador de dispisitivo, pero no aparece y no encuentro la solucion
se entiende?

Comment: que marca es tu equipo, quizas debas bajar el driver segun la marca